# MYSQL - using SUM, JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have table users:

```
id|email            |credit
1 |test@test.com    |10
2 |test2@test2.com  |20
```

and table orders:

```
id|user_id|subtotal
1 |1      |10
2 |1      |20
3 |2      |30
```

I want to get summed credit per user when orders are joined

with query:

```
SELECT SUM(credit)
FROM users
GROUP BY users.id
```

I get correct results

```
10
20
```

but when join is added:

```
SELECT SUM(credit)
FROM users
JOIN orders ON orders.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

I get results:

```
20
20
```

Credit is doubled for user with id = 1 (because there are 2 orders).

How to rewrite query to get desired results?

I need to join orders to fetch some that from that table.

PS. I need to use SUM because I also want to group by day, week, month, etc. not just by users.id

Comment: why need sum of credit?

Comment: *`group by users.id`* ? this is not PK and may have duplicates?

Comment: It would be best if you expand your question and provide expected result instead of insisting that you absolutely have to use `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to do it:

```sql
SELECT users.id,  
    min(credits) as credits
from users 
JOIN orders on orders.user_id = users.id 
group by users.id
```

```
id|credits|
--+-------+
 1|10     |
 2|20     |
```

-> please check fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3aca20eef0864c4a4303e331f2fc50c4)

Comment: I want SUM not MIN

Comment: Why need sum. In user table user id is unique... so single credit per user. Isn't it?

Comment: I want to use SUM because then I can group by day, week, etc. not just by users.id –

Comment: on orders table

Comment: check my answer on that question

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that works:

```
SELECT 
    users.id,
    SUM(
        IF(orders.id = (
           SELECT 
                id
            FROM
                orders o
            WHERE
                o.user_id = users.id
            LIMIT 1),
        users.credit,
        0))
FROM
    users
        JOIN
    orders ON orders.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: it's it different, do you want to substruct [subtotals](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=486bd42892cee04639a3fe9fb82cb55f) ?

Comment: do you want to calculate daily weekly, monthly totals? like in the last [query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=597fcf16e311621de5118de982bbbcd6) ?

Comment: it also works with [subtotal](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10c6323e332ee7971ac760412397d119)